# Printing PDF documents from an ASP.NET core web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, printing

I am using the below method to print my PDF documents. It works perfectly running on my local machine. But once I upload to webserver, I get an error printing. I suspect it is the path, but I don't know what is going wrong?
Any help appreciated as I am soon going to resort to pulling my hair out !!

Upon further investigation, I see that I need to assign a default local printer.
My code was looking for the web servers printer. Anyone could assist with that ?
Is there anything I should be aware of when printing from a web application?
I have set the default printer on the end users machine, but am still getting errors from this code?
I also need to show the print dialog before printing.

And lastly, can we print to a LOCAL printer from an ASP.NET .core web application? Or do they BOTH have to be on the SAME network ?

Thanks.

```
private void PrintEntireCatologue()
{
    var RowsData = DataGrid.CurrentViewData;
 
    foreach (ClientDoc row in RowsData)
    {
            var PdfToPrint =  row.DocPathAzure; /*get file name from database*/
            var doctoprint = @".\wwwroot\Pdfdocs" + PdfToPrint; /*Get directory path*/
            PdfDocumentProcessor documentProcessor = new PdfDocumentProcessor();
            documentProcessor.LoadDocument(doctoprint);
            PdfPrinterSettings pdfPrinterSettings = new PdfPrinterSettings();
            pdfPrinterSettings.PageOrientation = PdfPrintPageOrientation.Portrait;
            documentProcessor.Print(pdfPrinterSettings);

    }
    toastService.ShowSuccess("Printing Complete.");
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the location of the webapp and printer more cleary? It seems that you have a server which your webapp runs on,  and an end user PC which have a default printer, and you want to print PDF from server to your end user PC's printer?

Comment: Could you please confirm few things? 
1. running locally means as in debug more or deployed in IIS
2. Hosted on web server - does that mean on IIS
3. Is it .Net core or .Net framework - if .Net core is it "in process" hosting ?

Comment: @neohope Yes, you got it! In the interim, my ISP (smarterasp.net) has informed me that no printing will be allowed under these circumstances. The document must first be downloaded, then printed on the client. I sometimes have 1000's to print(huge catalogs'), so was looking for a solution with one button click. It seems the only way is to ZIP them all up, then download zip file and have a utility program that does the job on the clients PC.

Comment: @mbshambharkar It is a Blazor server application. When running locally, I was running it through Visual studio 2019, but it was on the same network as the printer was, so it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It works locally for you because the command is being run on your machine. When the application is deployed, the command is run on the server. Your C# code never reaches the client; the code is compiled as you build it, and even the Blazor pages are compiled server-side before being sent to the client. Unless you can use the client to reach the client's printer, there's no way to print directly from the server.

I suggest you create a piece of JavaScript that would download the file from the server, then access the printer on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do that, ex.

1. Cloud printing service

Send the documents to the cloud. Your clients can print any where.

2. Document server + script

Send the documents to the document server. On your client's PC, create a cron job, check the server from time to time, download then document, send the documents to the printer.

3. Document server + End user print utility

Send your documents to the document server. The print utility check the server from time to time, download then document, send the documents to the printer.

4. Document server + Website

Send your documents to the document server. The end user log in your website, click print. Then use js to print your documents.

Anyway, you need a server to store the documents, and an utility to get the document and send the document to the end user's printer.

Comment: Sometimes you need to think about you ask. What if I created a web application that automagically sent a 10,000 page file to your printer. I bet you would not be pleased. There are reasons such things do not or cannot work.

Comment: @kevinBrown Really ? All users of the system are paying customers who pay up front for a year. The documents they are printing are restricted to the one's on offer, so no "10,000" page doc could be sent. And secondly, that would get an instant ban on the system and they would lose their payment.

Comment: @neohope Thanks for the heads up. Yes, this seems like the only way to go. I am going to get a VPS on Azure which will allow me to control the entire machine.